# Why does this Java parseInt hex string result in NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, parseint

```
Integer.parseInt("ff8ca87c", 16);
```

This gives me a NumberFormatException for some reason. Do you know why that is?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ff8ca87c"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: @John3136 yes, it doesn't work either

Comment: @John3136 - The spec doesn't mention the `0x` prefix at all.

Comment: You are probably right - 0x would actually be on an int v=0xabcd rather than in a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it fails is that you're trying to put `+0xff8ca87c` into a signed integer. The maximum value of a 32-bit signed integer is `+0x7fffffff`, because the most significant bit is used to store the sign.

Try using a `long` instead. The maximum value of a 64-bit signed int is `0x7fffffffffffffff`, which is more than adequate for your needs in this case.

Or, in Java 8 you can use `Integer.parseUnsignedInt("ff8ca87c", 16);` which will treat the value as an unsigned integer.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't really thinking about that. I confused the signed and unsigned int bounds. Unfortunately I'll have to test if parsing to long, and converting back to int effects the values of the bits (pesky sign bit!)

Comment: Surprisingly no, the bits all stay consistent through the whole conversion, process. Useful!

Comment: You might find Guava's [UnsignedInts.parseUnsignedInt](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInts.html#parseUnsignedInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) relevant.